# Adjacency of intersected sets

Tags: algorithm, collision-detection, collision, adjacency-list

Given a known number **N** of sets of items. Each set containing exactly **D - 1** (**N >= D**) unique (within the set) items. But each item shared between **D - 1** sets. Therefore every set have two "neighbouring" sets: both neighbours differs by exactly one element. Also every set have (if **D** is big enough) two more distant neighbouring sets, that differs by exactly two elements, etc. All sets together forms a closed chain.

E.g. there are ten elements `a x b n q p j t r c`. **D = 4**. And sets are (in parentheses are hints for possible ordering of neighbouring sets):

```
c x j (1)
p j x (2)
x a p (3)
p a n (4)
n q b (6)
a n q (5)
b r t (8)
b q t (7)
j c r (0)
c t r (9)
```

=> respective chain of items is: `r c j x p a n q b t`. The example generated as the result of *backward substitution*. But how to perform the restoration of the neighbourhood algoritmically **?**

[One way is obvious](https://bitbucket.org/tomilov/quickhull/src/717891e35623933e9a47ba0250fbf4b9b1e207aa/include/quickhull.hpp?at=master#cl-474): simply enumerate all possible pairs of sets and compare sets from each pair whether they are differs exactly by one element or not (also there possible small optimizations, but they not matters much).

[Another way to solve the problem](https://gitorious.org/qhull/qhull/source/60d55819729d7b49391dde0271e15a56c70992b9:src/libqhull/poly.c#L836) is to generate (for each set from input) hashes for all possible **D - 2**-tuples of ordered sets of elements, then find pairs of collisions. There is a knowledge domain called [Locality-Sensitive Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing).

Both approaches seems to me as a full opposites. Hashing is faster, but implies the adjustment (of buckets sizes, choosing the way of hash combining for vector elements etc.) and most of its operations have *amortized* constant time. So, there involved some probabilistic actions. I can conclude, that for some **D** and **N** there is possibility to encounter performance degradation.

I suspect that there is a deterministic (in above sense) way to find all the neighbouring (adjacent) sets.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `O(D*N)` solution.

Two sets are defined to be neighbors if they differ in exactly 1 element. E.g. `xap` and `pan`.

Define `N` buckets, each labeled with a single element.

1. Place a copy of each set in each associated bucket. E.g. Bucket `a` holds `xap`, `pan`, and `anq`.
2. Start the chain by selecting any bucket, say `a`. Find 3 sets in the bucket that form a chain. E.g. `xap`, `pan`, `anq`. These are the first 3 sets in the chain.
3. Based on last two sets in the current chain, find the element in the last set that is not in the previous. For `pan` and `anq`, this is `q`. Go to this bucket.
4. In the present bucket, find the set which is a neighbor of the last element in the chain. E.g. in bucket `q`, the set neighboring `anq` is `nqb`. Add this set to the chain. Go to previous step until you circle back to the first set of the chain, e.g. `xap`.

One slight optimization is to remove sets from buckets once they are put into the chain.

Comment: I'll try to implement.

Comment: There is issue: how to ordering `xap`, `pan` and `anq` on first step. It is not zero-cost operation.

Comment: You're not ordering all the sets in that bucket; only 3, no matter how large `D` is. You should be able to do this in `O(D*D)` steps using the method you described in your question as the "obvious" method, but limited just to this bucket.